# Maven Classifier: how to personalize pom.xml to don't pick all dependencies of the project

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I created a lib jar with all my DTO to share with my consumer by using classifiers.

It's not so bad excepted the pom.xml archived in my lib because is the one of the main project.

I would like to find a way to simply or replace this file during the packaging to have only the needed dependancies.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>dtos</id>
         <goals>
               <goal>jar</goal>
         </goals>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <configuration>
            <classifier>dtos</classifier>
            <includes>
               <include>fr/my/lovely/company/api/dtos/*.class</include>
            </includes>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
 </executions>
<plugin>
```

Have you got any idea?

Thank you

Comment: First why created a jar with a classifier? What is the reason for that?

Comment: We though that is an easy way to keep our dto in the main project and share it with the others. without create a miniproject  with just some dto inside

Comment: Create a multi module project and move the dto parts which you like to share into a separate module...then it's easier also you can define it's own needed dependencies and it's a clean separation of concern...and finally no classifier needed... and no supplemental configuration needed...